Using Solver in VBA
I am trying to create a function which uses the Solver but I am getting a runtime error 438 method range of object worksheet failed.  Please see code below:
Function DepreciationProfilingMethod(WS As Worksheet, Var As Range, Adj As Range)

    SolverReset
    SolverOptions Assumenonneg:=False
    SolverOK SetCell:=WS.Range("Var"), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=WS.Range("Adj"), EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve (True)
End Function

Sub RunDepreciationMacro()
    
    Dim C_TRS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim WorkB As Workbook
    Set C_TRS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C_TRS")
    Set WorkB = ThisWorkbook
    Call addsolver 
   'Error in this line
    Call DepreciationProfilingMethod(C_TRS, C_TRS.Range("Var_2023"), C_TRS.Range("Adj_2023"))
End Sub

I have tried to add a worksheet as a parameter to the function but this has not resolved the error and not sure how to resolve this.

Try SolverOK SetCell:=Var, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Adj, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear". Adj and Var are Range object argument. You can't use it as WS.Range("Var").

Noted thanks, I've updated to remove worksheet, however now I am getting a run=time error 13 type mismatch. Please note that Var is a single cell named range and Adj is a range of cells

take the quotes out of "Var" assuming that's the address you're passing. If it's a named range LITERALLY being "VAR" than there's no need for the parameter. Also, be more specific where the error is. A``type` error is just the wrong type of object (so like instead of a number it's getting a range) and should be easy to fix.

Thanks very much for your help, I have removed the quotation marks. I am now getting this error: Run-time error 1004, method Range of object _Worksheet failed in the following line of code:
Call DepreciationProfilingMethod(C_TRS.Range(Var_2023), C_TRS.Range(Adj_2023))
It feels like a really easy fix, I'm just missing something obvious!
